# Django-filter with DRF - How to do 'and' when applying multiple values with the same lookup?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

This is a slightly simplified example of the filterset I'm using, which I'm using with the DjangoFilterBackend for Django Rest Framework. I'd like to be able to send a request to `/api/bookmarks/?title__contains=word1&title__contains=word2` and have results returned that contain both words, but currently it ignores the first parameter and only filters for word2.

Any help would be very appreciated!

```
class BookmarkFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Bookmark
        fields = {
            'title': ['startswith', 'endswith', 'contains', 'exact', 'istartswith', 'iendswith', 'icontains', 'iexact'],
        }

class BookmarkViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BookmarkSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = BookmarkFilter
    ordering_fields = ('title', 'date', 'modified')
    ordering = '-modified'
    page_size = 10
```

Comment: Can you also paste your view code which use the defined filter backend.

Comment: Check the issues here [filter on a field for a set of values (OR between values)](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/137#issuecomment-77697870)

Comment: @shady I've read that issue thread. The code you linked to provides a solution for ORing between values but not AND. Posted view code above. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, then you should consider to overwrite the get_queryset instead.@ergusto

Comment: Can you explain how that would help? The initial queryset won't affect how filtering is performed. @shady

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The main problem is that you need a filter that understands how to operate on multiple values. There are basically two options:

- Use `MultipleChoiceFilter` (not recommended for this instance)
- Write a custom filter class

**Using `MultipleChoiceFilter`**

```py
class BookmarkFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    title__contains = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(
        name='title',
        lookup_expr='contains',
        conjoined=True,  # uses AND instead of OR
        choices=[???],
    )

    class Meta:
        ...
```

While this retains your desired syntax, the problem is that you have to construct a list of choices. I'm not sure if you can simplify/reduce the possible choices, but off the cuff it seems like you would need to fetch all titles from the database, split the titles into distinct words, then create a set to remove duplicates. This seems like it would be expensive/slow depending on how many records you have.

**Custom `Filter`**

Alternatively, you can create a custom filter class - something like the following:

```py
class MultiValueCharFilter(filters.BaseCSVFilter, filters.CharFilter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        # value is either a list or an 'empty' value
        values = value or []

        for value in values:
            qs = super(MultiValueCharFilter, self).filter(qs, value)

        return qs


class BookmarkFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    title__contains = MultiValueCharFilter(name='title', lookup_expr='contains')

    class Meta:
        ...
```

Usage (notice that the values are comma-separated):

```
GET /api/bookmarks/?title__contains=word1,word2
```

Result:

```
qs.filter(title__contains='word1').filter(title__contains='word2')
```

The syntax is changed a bit, but the CSV-based filter doesn't need to construct an unnecessary set of choices.

Note that it isn't really possible to support the `?title__contains=word1&title__contains=word2` syntax as the widget can't render a suitable html input. You would either need to use `SelectMultiple` (which again, requires choices), or use javascript on the client to add/remove additional text inputs with the same `name` attribute.

---

Without going into too much detail, filters and filtersets are just an extension of Django's forms.

- A `Filter` has a form `Field`, which in turn has a `Widget`.
- A `FilterSet` is composed of `Filter`s.
- A `FilterSet` generates an inner form based on its filters' fields.

Responsibilities of each filter component:

- The widget retrieves the raw value from the `data` [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict).
- The field validates the raw value.
- The filter constructs the `filter()` call to the queryset, using the validated value.

In order to apply multiple values for the same filter, you would need a filter, field, and widget that understand how to operate on multiple values.

---

The custom filter achieves this by mixing in `BaseCSVFilter`, which in turn mixes in a "comma-separation => list" functionality into the composed field and widget classes.

I'd recommend looking at the source code for the CSV mixins, but in short:

- The [widget](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/1.0.1/django_filters/widgets.py#L142-L170) splits the incoming value into a list of values.
- The [field](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/1.0.1/django_filters/widgets.py#L142-L170) validates the entire list of values by validating individual values on the 'main' field class (such as `CharField` or `IntegerField`). The field also derives the mixed in widget.
- The [filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/1.0.1/django_filters/filters.py#L519-L561) simply derives the mixed in field class.

The CSV filter was intended to be used with `in` and `range` lookups, which accept a list of values. In this case, `contains` expects a single value. The `filter()` method fixes this by iterating over the values and chaining together individual  filter calls.

Comment: First of all a huge thank you for such a thorough post. It's cleared up a lot of things I had a fuzzy understanding of. I tried implementing your MultiValueCharFilter and unfortunately filtering with multiple values using the comma syntax returned 0 results, but no errors. Filtering with one value worked fine though. I looked through the source and from what I can tell it should work, so not sure what is wrong with it. Am I right in thinking this will work with most other types of filter in place of CharFilter? Again, many thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that was off the top of my head as something that should be roughly correct. I didn't actually take the time to test it. You are correct that it should work with other types of filters, such as `NumberFilter`. That said, there are only a few where it would actually make sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution with BaseCSVFilter does not work properly when title contains commas

Comment: Where MultiValueFilter came from?

Comment: `MultiValueFilter` is a typo. It should be `MultiValueCharFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom list field something like this:

```
from django.forms.widgets import SelectMultiple
from django import forms

class ListField(forms.Field):
    widget = SelectMultiple

    def __init__(self, field, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListField, self).__init__( *args, **kwargs)
        self.field = field

    def validate(self, value):
        super(ListField, self).validate(value)
        for val in value:
            self.field.validate(val)

    def run_validators(self, value):
        for val in value:
            self.field.run_validators(val)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value:
            return []
        elif not isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_list'], code='invalid_list')
        return [self.field.to_python(val) for val in value]
```

and create custom filter using MultipleChoiceFilter:

```
class ContainsListFilter(django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter):
    field_class = ListField

    def get_filter_predicate(self, v):
        name = '%s__contains' % self.name
        try:
            return {name: getattr(v, self.field.to_field_name)}
        except (AttributeError, TypeError):
            return {name: v}
```

After that you can create FilterSet with your custom filter:

```
from django.forms import CharField

class StorageLocationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    title_contains = ContainsListFilter(field=CharField())
```

Working for me. Hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that just works:
it supports - product?name=p1,p2,p3 and will return products with name (p1,p2,p3)

```
def resolve_csvfilter(queryset, name, value):
    lookup = { f'{name}__in': value.split(",") }
    queryset = queryset.filter(**lookup)
    return queryset

class ProductFilterSet(FilterSet):
        name = CharFilter(method=resolve_csvfilter)
    
        class Meta:
            model = Product
            fields = ['name']
```

Ref: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method
https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/137

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who want to use **OR / IN** instead of **AND**:

```
from django_filters import MultipleChoiceFilter
from django_filters.fields import MultipleChoiceField


class MultipleCharField(MultipleChoiceField):
    def validate(self, _):
        pass


class MultipleCharFilter(MultipleChoiceFilter):
    field_class = MultipleCharField
```

**Usage:**

```
class BookmarkFilter(FilterSet):
    title = MultipleCharFilter(field_name="title", lookup_expr="contains")
```

**Request:**

`/api/bookmarks/?title=Title1&title=Title2`

Check this issue for more detail: [GitHub](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/1076)