# How to do 'or' when applying multiple values with the same lookup?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

By referring to this article, I was able to implement the method of `and` search.

[Django-filter with DRF - How to do 'and' when applying multiple values with the same lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194200/django-filter-with-drf-how-to-do-and-when-applying-multiple-values-with-the)

I want to know how to do `or` search for multiple keywords using the same field. How can I implement it?

---

Here is the code:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from .serializers import BookInfoSerializer
from .models import BookInfo


class MultiValueCharFilter(filters.BaseCSVFilter, filters.CharFilter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        # value is either a list or an 'empty' value
        values = value or []

        for value in values:
            qs = super(MultiValueCharFilter, self).filter(qs, value)

        return qs


class BookInfoFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    title = MultiValueCharFilter(lookup_expr='contains')
    # title = MultiValueCharFilter(lookup_expr='contains', conjoined=False) -> get an error

    class Meta:
        model = BookInfo
        fields = ['title']


class BookInfoAPIView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = BookInfo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookInfoSerializer
    filter_class = BookInfoFilter
```

if I set `conjoined=False` like this `title = MultiValueCharFilter(lookup_expr='contains', conjoined=False)` get an error `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'conjoined'`

---

Django              3.2.5

django-filter       2.4.0

djangorestframework 3.12.4

Python              3.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to modify the queryset returned from **MultiValueCharFilter**
and combine values with operator.

example:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

class MultiValueCharFilter(BaseCSVFilter, CharFilter):

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        expr = reduce(
            operator.or_,
            (Q(**{f'{self.field_name}__{self.lookup_expr}': v}) for v in value)
        )
        return qs.filter(expr)


class BookInfoFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    title = MultiValueCharFilter(lookup_expr='contains')

    class Meta:
        model = BookInfo
        fields = ['title']
```

Comment: This worked as I expected. Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a new Class called ListFilter like this:

```
from django_filters.filters import Filter
from django_filters.conf import settings as django_filters_settings
from django.db.models.constants import LOOKUP_SEP


class ListFilter(Filter):
    """
    Custom Filter for filtering multiple values.
    """
    def __init__(self, query_param: str, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Override default variables.
        Args:
            query_param (str): Query param in URL
        """
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.query_param = query_param
        self.distinct = True

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        """
        Override filter method in Filter class.
        """
        try:
            request = self.parent.request
            values = request.query_params.getlist(self.query_param)
            # Remove empty value in array
            values = list(filter(None, values))
        except AttributeError:
            values = []

        # Filter queryset by using OR expression when lookup_expr is 'in'
        # Else filter queryset by using AND expression
        if values and self.lookup_expr == 'in':
            return super().filter(qs, values)

        for value in set(values):
            predicate = self.get_filter_predicate(value)
            qs = self.get_method(qs)(**predicate)

        return qs.distinct() if self.distinct else qs

    def get_filter_predicate(self, value):
        """
        This function helps to get predicate for filtering
        """
        name = self.field_name

        if (
            name
            and self.lookup_expr != django_filters_settings.DEFAULT_LOOKUP_EXPR
        ):
            name = LOOKUP_SEP.join([name, self.lookup_expr])

        return {name: value}
```

My class above supports filter nested fields using both OR and AND expressions. E.g. about filter `title` field using OR expression:

```
class BookInfoFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    title = ListFilter(query_param='title')

    class Meta:
        model = BookInfo
        fields = ['title']
```

Comment: It doesn't work for my case...I can't get any data even for one keyword search without using or search.