# Filter for several items of the same field Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a view like this:

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    filter_class = ProductFilter
```

and ProductFilter:

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['brand']
```

the problem is that when I send a `GET /products/?brand=Adidas+Nike`, I get an error `[ "Select a valid choice. Nike Adidas is not one of the available choices." ]`

How can I fix it that it will filter for several items of the same field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django-filter with DRF - How to do 'and' when applying multiple values with the same lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194200/django-filter-with-drf-how-to-do-and-when-applying-multiple-values-with-the)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use [MultipleChoiceFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/main/ref/filters.html#multiplechoicefilter) on this field, it will by default use an OR logic (Nike or Adidas).